# Exclude level from modx frendly url - modx

Tags: friendly-url, modx

I'm wondering, if it's even possible to exclude certain level from Modx Friendly-urls.

I would like to get from this:
http://www.example.com/level1/**level2**/level3

to this:
http://www.example.com/level1/level3

I saw looking in Modx System settings and mod_rewrite for .htaccess but couldn't make it work.
Did anyone have the same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

I have installed Custom URLs extra: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/CustomUrls

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Your level 2 item is just a folder or landing page with no content? That's why you want to hide it? You can use the Freeze URI setting in the child resources to hide the folder.

Comment: This is the real correct answer. Just go to settings->freeze URI and set it to as you wish.